# Try to grep out varnish version does not work

Tags: linux, grep, varnish

I try to read the varnish version from a Linux Command line, but the following does not work:

```
varnishd -V | grep -P '(?<=varnish-)[0-9.]+' -o
```

This always returns this

```
varnishd (varnish-3.0.3 revision 9e6a70f)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Varnish Software AS
```

instead of just this

```
3.0.3
```

Any hints on what I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you just want the digits in decimal form, you will need something like grep -o '[0-9].[0.9].[0-9]'

Comment: But this works: "httpd -version | grep -P '(?<=Apache/)[0-9.]+' -o". 
So why should this not work on the varnish version command?

Comment: Perhaps `varnishd -V` writes to `stderr` not `stdout`? Try appending `2>&1`

Comment: @steeldriver You were absolutely right. I needed to redirect the stderr to the stdout. Now it works like a charm: 'varnishd -V 2>&1 | grep -P '(?<=varnish-)[0-9.]+' -o'
If you make an answer out of it, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `varnishd -V` writes to `stderr` not `stdout`. In order to pipe the result into `grep`, you will need to redirect the stream e.g.

```
varnishd -V 2>&1 | grep -P '(?<=varnish-)[0-9.]+' -o
```